# what is the list for list of sexual orientation options in a dating website?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, terminology, registration, psychology

**males and females sexual orientations in a terminology that is easy for the user to select them.** 
***Exmple .male straight , female straight*** 
including gay and lesbian and other kinds.

> please i am waiting certainly for a **list** the user will be able to
>   select from it as an answer to
>    " **you are interested in "...........**"

Comment: Off topic...perhaps the http://english.stackexchange.com/ can help you.

Comment: Why ? its about user when he select the gender
"he is interested in "

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it might be better suited for english.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is no one 'the list'. This isn't really a UX question. It's a psychology/biology/sociology question.

Comment: But to keep it semi-on topic, Facebook recently came out with their list of sexual orientation options: http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/02/15/the-complete-glossary-of-facebook-s-51-gender-options.html

Comment: I think the usability question is how to best empower your users to describe themselves in a meaningful and useful way.  This is a very timely question as evidenced by facebook.  Were the question rephrased to represent that, it would be absolutely within scope for this site.

Comment: It could be a simple sentence to fill in: " I am a (fe)male interested in [both] (fe)males [and (fe)males]". Or make it a list of radio buttons that includes all variation of this sentence.

Comment: DA01 damn that list... Must +1 since 51 gender options is just madness... Why in a logical world people have to go on and screw up everything ;D *drunk*

Comment: Don't list sexual orientations. There are 4 options: Man seeking Woman, Man seeking Man, Woman seeking Man, and Woman seeking Woman.

Comment: what if you are seeking men for a friendship that you wouldnt mind? @MickaelCaruso

the aim in making people in categories

Comment: @DA01 Those are not sexual orientation options at facebook, they are gender identity options. There's a very big difference.

Comment: @MickaelCaruso That's assuming there are only 2 genders, which Facebook amongst others recognises is not the case.

Comment: @Erics yes, that's a good clarification.

Comment: Why in the world would this not be a UX question? Choosing which options to offer an end user is purely UX. 
Why did facebook choose to change their gender options? Because they found that their limited list offended some users, or made it impossible to register. Image you want to register you car online. You can choose every brand in the world, except for the Tesla you are driving. This must be the pinnacle of miscreated UX.

Comment: I think that it is impossible to work with predefined categories here. You get 50-ish gender identifications for the searcher if you go with the FB list, multiply that by 50-ish for the searched. Then add polyamory ("I am a man looking for a couple in which one partner is bigender") and you see how you can never cover it all with closed lists. I would use three categories (female, male, other) for the searcher, three for the searched, and a freetext input of limited length for self-identification. People will have to search in both the category and this field at once.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology not UX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have always assumed that there are only 2 types of people: men and women. Which is wrong. [Facebook has finally realised it.](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/technology/facebook-gender-option-facebooks-new-3144022)

Sexual orientation is not much more than 2 lists of "genders" with a 1 to n relation.

Example: Person X may be a transsexual man looking for both bigenders and Cis Females.

This may be an exaggerated example and not suitable for the target audience for your website, but the point I'd like to make: it really **not** as simple as 4 options (men looking for men - men looking for women - women looking for men - women looking for women)